# SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail access denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am using CSOM("SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail") to send email to the members of my site collection.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: webUrl + "SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": xdigestdata.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue,
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                }).then(function(result, status) {
                    console.log("Email Sent!");
                    deferred.resolve(result);
                }, function(result, status) {
                    console.log("sendEmails: " + JSON.stringify(result2))
                    deferred.reject(result);
                });
```

I got no problem using it, I wass able to send and receive the email I am sending but I got problem when the application I created was being used by a user that only has "Members" permission. I am getting the following error. Note when I switch back my test account as Site Owner I was able send again my email. Is there any specific permission that I need to give to members group to send email or is there any specific list that members group should have access to, to send email?

"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
message
:
lang
:
"en-US"
value
:
"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or acc

Answer (score 0):

Users need to have the `Manage Alerts - Manage alerts for all users of the Web site` Permission on the site level to send emails. See [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/16977) and [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2) for more details on the Manage Alerts permission.

You will need to enable this for the group or users in `Permission Levels : Edit Permission Level`